# Laravel jobs delay at exact time

Tags: php, laravel, jobs, php-carbon

I tried to specify the exact time to process the job task in laravel:

```
$date = "2021-11-09 12:34:00";
$date = Carbon::parse($date)->timestamp;
JobsPublishArticle::dispatch()->delay($date);
```

the dd($date) give `1636461240` but in my jobs table i got `3272918981`;
It's like it added my date to the timestamp gived by `now()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$date = "2021-11-09 12:34:00";
$carbonDate = Carbon::parse($date);
JobsPublishArticle::dispatch()->delay($carbonDate);
```